# Check if device has an apple ID logged in/enabled

Tags: ios, apple-id

I am trying to detect if there is an Apple ID which is logged in a iOS device.

Basically if user is
1. logged into iTunes or app store.
2. logged into iCloud.

In general if there is a Apple id used in device.

Is there a possible swift way to check?

Comment: In what sense would one be "logged in" with an Apple ID? Do you mean iCloud?

Comment: Not just iCloud. Apple ID can be used to log into iTunes and apple store.  Editing the question to reflect the same

Comment: I still don't understand the idea. My iPhone is never "logged into iTunes and App Store". If I need to download an app, for example, I'll be asked to authenticate then and there; there is no _state_ of being "logged in".

Comment: In app store, for downloading you are not authenticating. You are authorizing. You are already logged into app-store. If you open app-store app, the top right corner has your profile image which say you are already logged in. On click on that image, you will see your apple-id details.